# How to turn a dataframe of categorical data into a dictionary

Tags: python, json, dataframe, transformation

I have a dataframe that I need to transform into JSON. I think it would be easier to first turn it into a dictionary, but I can't figure out how. I need to transform it into JSON so that I can visualize it with js.d3

Here is what the data looks like currently:

```
NAME, CATEGORY, TAG
Ex1, Education, Books
Ex2, Transportation, Bus
Ex3, Education, Schools
Ex4, Education, Books
Ex5, Markets, Stores
```

Here is what I want the data to look like:

```
Data = {
     Education {
        Books {
           key: Ex1,
           key: Ex2 
}
Schools {
key: Ex3
}
}
Transportation {
Bus {
key: Ex2
}
}
Markets {
Stores {
key: Ex5
}
}
```

(I think my JSON isn't perfect here, but I just wanted to convey the general idea).

Comment: Is the data currently in a text file?  Your format looks CSV-ish but don't want to assume anything.

Comment: I see the Python tag.... Do you mean a pandas DataFrame? If so, see [this branch](https://github.com/pydata/pandasjson).

Comment: The data is currently in a CSV file.

Comment: Yea I imported it as a pandas DataFrame, I'll check out the link, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use 'key' as a key more than once, so the innermost group is a list:

```
import json, string

def to_json(file):
    data = {}
    for line in open(file):
        fields = map(string.strip, line.split(','))
        categories = data.get(fields[1], {})
        tags = categories.get(fields[2], [])
        tags.append(fields[0])
        categories[fields[2]] = tags
        data[fields[1]] = categories
    return json.dumps(data)

print to_json('data.csv')
```

Result:

```
{"Markets": {"Stores": ["Ex5"]}, "Education": {"Schools": ["Ex3"], "Books": ["Ex1", "Ex4"]}, "Transportation": {"Bus": ["Ex2"]}}
```

Comment: This was very very helpful. Thanks!! I needed to make some changes to the data, so I changed the code a little and posted it as an answer in case others run into similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

This code is thanks to Brent Washburne's very helpful answer above. I just needed to remove the tags column because for now it was too messy (many of the rows had more than one tag separated by commas). I also added a column (of integers) which I wanted connected to the names. Here it is:

```
import json, string
import pprint

def to_json(file):
data = {}
for line in open(file):
    fields = map(string.strip, line.split(','))
    categories = data.get(fields[1], [])
    to_append = {}       
    to_append[fields[0]] = fields[3]
    categories.append(to_append)
    data[fields[1]] = categories
return json.dumps(data)

print to_json('data.csv')
```